# Wpf navigation frame inside a frame, navigation button are disabled in child

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, user-controls, frame

I have into solution

1. (A) wpf user control project (library dll): this has an user control which has  a frame, own navigation buttons and a menu to navigate between some Pages which are also defined in this project.
2. (B) wpf application (test): I used to test the dll. It has only a main window which has uses the  user control defined in the previous project.
3. (C) wpf application (let's say the final project) which is more complex. This has also a frame with own navigation button and own menu. The frame has to show several pages defined in this project and also the user control of A.

When I use (B) to test (A) everything works fine.
When I use (C) to show (A) the navigation button of A are disabled, and instead the navigation button of C works for pages of A and C.

It looks that the all the commands sent to the frame of C are instead sent to the parent frame of A.

How is it possible?

I have my navigation button with custom UIRoutedCommand

```
private void Backward_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = ChildFrame?.CanGoBack??false;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

ChildFrame?.CanGoBack is always false when A is used by C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I wrote the question too fast, instead of read MSDN documentation...

```
<Frame x:Name="ChildFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal">
```

JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal" saved my day